# How to translate curl in guzzle

Tags: php, api, curl, guzzle

This curl approach works fine and I see my token

```
     $curl = curl_init($this->communityUrl . 'api' . $this->endpointCategories);                 
     $array = [
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => TRUE,
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT       => "MyUserAgent/1.0",
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER  => array( "Authorization: Bearer {$token}" ),
      ];

      curl_setopt_array($curl, $array);

      $response = curl_exec($curl);
```

Now I tried to translate in guzzle to have the same result

```
     $headers = [
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer :' . $token,
        'User-Agent: MyUserAgent/1.0'
//        'User-Agent' => 'MyUserAgent/1.0' // try this also not work see php loop
      ];

      $response = HTTP::getResponse([
        'url' =>  $this->communityUrl . 'api' . $this->endpointCategories,
        'header' => $headers,
        'method' => 'GET'
      ]);
```

Inside my php code I have this loop

```
if (!empty($data['header'])) {
        foreach ($data['header'] as $h) {
          [$key, $value] = explode(':', $h, 2); 

          $options['headers'][$key] = $value;

          unset($key);
          unset($value);
        }
      }
```

the result is like this but I have a trigger error. Maybe I do something wrong

```
HTTP::getResponse($data = ['url' => 'https://www.mywebsite.com/forum/api/downloads/categories?perPage=150', 'header' => ['Authorization' => 'Bearer :6a957ad3fec7dc151b8fa9c5dcb7e63a_67e4abf29ee40225b2b9272c822d14e2eb890fff1b7f68e29fb944dce0b4d109', 0 => 'User-Agent: MyUserAgent/1.0'], 'method' => 'GET']) 

[15-Jan-2023 21:59:43 UTC] PHP   6. trigger_error($message = '"Bearer " is not valid header name')
```

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried to remove the colon in 'Bearer :6a9..', colon shouldn't be needed there.